# In Python, when I have a variable set to an input, and the input matches an if statement, why does it still run my else code?

Tags: python

I'm a Python beginner and I have started to code a basic area calculator (code is shown below). My idea was to separate each shape's calculating code into its own function and then have if and elif statements decide which function to call based on input from the user. Currently, my program only calculates the area of squares (this code, located in the square function, is all correct). When I input "square", the program still runs the else code instead! Could someone please help me understand what I did wrong? (This is in Python version 3.3.3, if that makes a difference).

```
def square():
    length = input("Please enter the length: ")
    width = input("Please enter the width: ")


def whole():

    area_product = int(length) * int(width)

    print("The area of your rectangle is " + str(area_product) + " :)" )

def decimal():

    area_product = float(length) * float(width)

    print("The area of your rectangle is " + str(area_product) + " :)" )


if float(length) % 1 == 0 and float(width) % 1 == 0:
    whole()

else:
    decimal()

choice = input("Please the select the shape that has the area you would like to calculate: ").lower()


if choice == square:
    square()
else:
    print("Sorry, the shape " + choice + " is not recognized. :( ")
```

Comment: It runs the `if` *or* the `else`. If it runs the `else` then the `if` conditions *failed*, despite what is believed - go back and check the assumptions. (P.S. the `width` and `length` variables set are *local variables* in the `square` function - using them elsewhere will be problematic. Also, `square` is a function so it'll never be "equals" the input..)

Comment: Whoever marked this as non-reproducible/typographic: this is reproducible, and it's not a typographic error. It's an error in OP's understanding of python syntax, but it's not a typo.

Answer (score 4):

`choice` will never equal `square`, because `square` is a function (or rather `square` is a variable whose value is a function), the value of `choice` is of the type returned by `input`, which is a string. Accordingly, the part under the `if` is never run, and the `else` is run instead.

What you want, probably is `if choice == 'square'`. It's a string, see?

Actually, you might want to do something more sophisticated, but that's the solution to this issue.